# VBA Button to drill down into PIvot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table in a my spreadsheet set up using slicers.  So depending on what's selected column A can vary between 1 row of data showing (excluding titles and grand total) and 50.

When you double click on 1 row that data gets opened up in a new sheet.
I'm trying to get a button to automatically open all the details that are in my pivot result. so if there was 1 result, press the button and 1 new sheet would be opened. if there was 9 results then 9 new sheets would be opened showing the underlying "drill down" data.

EDIT: 
I found some code, it almost works however it opens up new worksheets (which is correct) however each worksheet contains all of the information from what's displayed. I'd want it to breakdown each drilldown. Do you know how to modify this to make it work for what I need?

```
  Sub drill()
   Dim sel As Variant, aRng As Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 Sheets("sheet1").Select

   Range("A5").Select
   Set aRng = Range("A5")
   While aRng.Value <> "Grand Total"
     With Sheets("sheet1").PivotTables(1)
       sel = .GetPivotData.Address
     End With
     Range(sel).ShowDetail = True

     Range("a1").Select

     Sheets("sheet1").Activate
     Set aRng = aRng.Offset(1, 0)
   Wend

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Using the macro recorder, and correcting the code to fully qualify ranges and remove `Selection`, the end result is `Sheet2.Range("B4").ShowDetail = True` where Range("B4") is one of the cells in the values area of the pivot. That combined with [this](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) information on referencing different ranges within pivot tables, should help you get started.

Comment: Hi, I tried a few alterations of this and I wasn't getting anywhere. So I carried on my search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the code you posted to run without issues (particularly the `.GetPivotData.Address` part). However, the following code worked for me.

```
Sub drill()
   Dim sel As Variant, topRow As Long, firstCol As Long, sht As Worksheet
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sht = Sheets("sheet1")

    With sht.PivotTables(1)
        topRow = .DataBodyRange.Row 'This is the minimum row number of the pivot body (excluding titles)
        firstCol = .DataBodyRange.Column 'This is the minimum col number of the pivot body (excluding row labels)
        For Each sel In .RowRange.Resize(, 1) 'Selects only the first column cells of the row labels
            If sel.Row >= topRow And sel.Value <> "Grand Total" Then sht.Cells(sel.Row, firstCol).ShowDetail = True
        Next sel
    End With

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```