# Pivot Drilldown Macro. Error when non sequential number

Tags: excel, vba

New to the community. I have a pivot drilldown macro that works fine most of the time,  but when there is a non sequential value in the column, I receive an error. "Run-Time error '1004' Unable to get DataRange property of the PivotItem class. Is there a way to get it to ignore the non sequential issue? The code I am using and works fine 90% of the time is below. I just need it to ignore if there is a number missing.
The code in this link also helped e, but it names the new sheeets "sheet 1" etc
[VBA Button to drill down into PIvot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535746/vba-button-to-drill-down-into-pivot-table)

Thanks

```
Dim pField As PivotField
Dim pItem As PivotItem
'Which pivotTable are we working with?
Set pField = Sheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("HFB")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop over each dept in that field
For Each pItem In pField.PivotItems
If pItem.Visible Then
pItem.DataRange.ShowDetail = True
ActiveSheet.Name = Right(pItem.Name, 4)
End If
Next pItem
```

Comment: Not the cleanest way but if the code works good except sometimes, you may benefit from `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`. Check [Error Handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/)

Comment: That allows the Macro to finish, but the Tab name is showing for the next data sets name. So everything after the error is named 1 HFB out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a bit more than just wrap the problem line in OERN:

```vb
Dim pField As PivotField
Dim pItem As PivotItem, rng As Range
'Which pivotTable are we working with?
Set pField = Sheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("HFB")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop over each dept in that field
For Each pItem In pField.PivotItems
    If pItem.Visible Then
        Set rng = Nothing           'clear range variable
        On Error Resume Next        'ignore errors
        Set rng = pItem.DataRange   'try to assign the range
        On Error Goto 0             'stop ignoring errors
        If not rng Is Nothing Then  'accessible range?
            rng.ShowDetail = True
            ActiveSheet.Name = Right(pItem.Name, 4)
        End If
    End If
Next pItem
```

Comment: Legend! That has worked like a charm. Really appreciate it. Thank you!