# Open pivot data 'grand total' on specific sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Hi hoping someone can help me with a problem,

i have a pivot table which is created by a macro, i want to be able to filter the pivot on various data, then click on the 'grand total' option to generate a table on a specific sheet.

i want to be able to automate the process of double clicking on the grand total and having this data displayed on worksheet 'D'

I then want to go back into the same pivot table, filter on a different 'desktoptype' and open the grand-total generated for this data on Worksheet 'S'

part of my code to generate pivot is below: i hope someone can provide some tips/guidance on how to get this working . (hopefully my description above makes sense) I am new to VBA so trying to get my head around what to do. Macro recorder isn't much help.

the following is an extract of code for my pivot creation :

```
Worksheets("D_S").Activate

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("D/S").TableRange2.Clear

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="D/S")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="D/S")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("D/S").PivotFields("DesktopType")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("D/S").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
"D/S").PivotFields("email"), "Count of email", xlCount
Quote ReplyReport
```

Comment: Your `On Error Resume Next` is hiding at least one error. Get rid of the first instance of `_
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="D/S")`. You have *two* instances of `CreatePivotTable` in the above code. You should also get rid of the blanket `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: thanks for highlighting this. Would you be able to provide any guidance on how would  be able to select the grand total figure on this pivot and have this data open up on a defined worksheet, ie "Sheet_s".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535746/vba-button-to-drill-down-into-pivot-table

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-to-open-the-grand-total-of-a-pivot-table-with-slicers-grand-total-is-not-always-in-the-same-cell.795307/